# AC works better when driving than when not driving

Tags: ford, ac, cooling-system

The weather outside today was more muggy than a 20 ounce mug with a pugs mug printed on it... being acquired in a mugging incident.

I mean it was hot.  Hotter than a hot place.

So... in my '98 Ford van, I noticed that the AC pumps colder air when the van is moving... but when I'm sittin in line for a burger, it still blows cold, but not as cold as when I'm drivin away eatin the burger afterwards.

But now I'm scared because I wonder if there is a problem with this van.

Is it normal for... the AC to pump colder when a vehicle is movin or is that not normal and so that means I gotta put my mechanic hat on and start investigatin?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, foward motion forces air through the condensor improving cooling, but when the vehicle is stationary this forced air does not happen and you have to rely on the cooling fan or fans.

If those fans are not working well that can have an effect as well.

The forced air cooling is also or sometimes called ram air cooling.